# How to make sure another person attended call successfully?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, network-programming, telprompt

From the application, I am able to call to an user, 
After my call ended I need to perform functionality

**The below method help me to call the user from the application.**

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:[[dictionaries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"phone"]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

How to make sure that the another person (call receiver) is successfully attended my call?

Your feedback is appreicated.

@Thanks in Advance!